# Visual Studio Code Coverage refuses to generate results

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage

I've run into a recurring problem with VS2015 Enterprise where it refuses to give me code coverage results:

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the
> tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files,
> and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information
> see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

I checked out the link, but none of the issues mentioned there apply to my situation: PDB files exist, tests ran, it's all managed code, etc.

In Event Viewer, I get the following errors every time I run code coverage analysis:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: IntelliTraceLogger Response: Not
> available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: IntelliTrace.EXE P2: 14.0.25123.0 P3: 56f22b85
> P4: Microsoft.IntelliTrace.14.0.0 P5: 14.0.25123.0 P6: 56f22b7c P7:
> 21df P8: 59 P9: System.IO.IOException P10:
>
> Attached files: Local\Temp\WER55C6.tmp.mdmp
> Local\Temp\WER5615.tmp.WERDataCollectionFailure.txt
>
> The TraceLog Profiler in process te.processhost.managed.exe logger not
> running after being started, command line "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\IntelliTrace.EXE"
> run /n:"intellitrace_00005914_01d1bd93494e70f1"
> /cp:"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TraceDebugger\Settings\fbxkbut5.agx"
> /f:"te.processhost.managed_00005914_160603_072725.iTrace".
>
> TraceLog Profiler failed initialization, process
> te.processhost.managed.exe